# Kotlin lambda compiles against java API but not against my own function

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

Here is a simplified example. This syntax works :

```
Handler().post({Log.v(TAG, "test")})
```

However, if I define this function

```
private fun doWithRunnable(toRun:Runnable) {
    // whatever
}
```

And call it like this

```
doWithRunnable({Log.v(TAG, "test")})
```

Then I get the following error:

> Required: Runnable
> Found: () -> Int

Both signatures look quite the same to me... what's the big difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java example, you're taking advantage of the Java-interop feature for [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). Unfortunately, this does not currently work for Kotlin interfaces, as the designers have deemed it unnecessary (there is some discussion on this see [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/sam-conversion-on-kotlin-interfaces/1433)).

Instead, you'd want to do something like:

```
fun doWithRunnable(runnable: () -> Any) {
    // call it as `runnable()`
}
```

You could also define a [typealias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) for this if you wanted (which is as close Kotlin comes to SAM syntax):

```
typealias RunMe = () -> Any

fun doWithRunnable(runnable: RunMe) {
    runnable()
}
```

Note that currently, typealiases have to be declared at the top level, they can't be declared inside a class or method.

Comment: Great! It all became luminous. I just defined `typealias KRunnable = () -> Unit` and use it "almost" as a regular Runnable.